# Adding textboxes and dropdown values(mathematical)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this dropdown menu that have three values and a two textboxes. I want their values to be added? How do I do that?

this is what i've got so far...

**html**

```
<select id="as">
       <option value="10.00">Additional of $10.00</option>
       <option value="20.00">Additional of $10.00</option>
       <option value="30.00">Additional of $10.00</option>
</select>

 <input type="text" id="txt1"/> //the value here is automatically shown
 <input type="text" id="txt2"/> //the value here is automatically shown
 <input type="text" id="total"/> //this is where the answer shows
```

**Javascript**

```
function subtotal(){
$("#as").change(function(){
    if ($(event.target)=='10.00'){

        var a = $("#txt1").val();
        var b = $("#txt2").val();
        var totalA = parseFloat(a, 10)+ parseFloat(b, 10);

        totalA = totalA + 10.00;
        $('#total').val('$' + totalA.toFixed(2));
    }else if ($(event.target)=='20.00'){
        var a = $("#txt1").val();
        var b = $("#txt2").val();
        var totalA = parseFloat(a, 10)+ parseFloat(b, 10);

        totalA = totalA + 20.00;
        $('#total').val('$' + totalA.toFixed(2));
    } else {
        var a = $("#txt1").val();
        var b = $("#txt2").val();
        var totalA = parseFloat(a, 10)+ parseFloat(b, 10);

        totalA = totalA + 30.00;
        $('#total').val('$' + totalA.toFixed(2));
    });
    }
```

p.s. you may ignore the automatic showing of the values in textbox because i have done it already and there's no errors. my main concern is the adding of dropdown values and textbox values

Comment: If your question 'how do i add options to a drop down via JavaScript'?

Comment: no. i already have my dropdown menu, i want its values to add in my textboxes...

i will add my html code. =)

Comment: Where is `#txt1` and `#txt2`?

Comment: sorry... typo... @hjpotter92

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of the 2 text boxes adding the value of the select.

```
  <select id="as">
    <option value="10.00">Additional of $10.00</option>
    <option value="20.00">Additional of $20.00</option>
    <option value="30.00">Additional of $30.00</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" id="txt1" />
  <input type="text" id="txt2" />
  <input type="text" id="total" />

  <script>
    $("#as").on('change', function(e) {
      var ddl = $(this).val();
      var txt1 = $('#txt1').val();
      var txt2 = $('#txt2').val();

      var a = parseFloat(ddl);
      var b = parseFloat(txt1);
      var c = parseFloat(txt2);
      var total = a + b + c;

      $('#total').val(total);
    });
  </script>
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/JlAffVadhKiW6HnbWqNx?p=preview

Comment: You can include the demo in your [so] post as well. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here

Comment: what if I will add a checkbox to the process? if it is checked, it will be added to the process, if not it will not be added.

Comment: You will just need to do a check on the checkbox and break out of the function if its false. eg if($('#checkbox:checked').length == 0) return;

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fny47hzt/) start from this.. hope it will help

```
subtotal();
function subtotal(){
$("#as").on('change',function(event){
    if ($(this).val() =='10.00'){

        var a = $("#sff").val();
        var b = $("#osf").val();
        var totalA = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);

        totalA = parseFloat(totalA) + 10.00;
        $('#total').val('$' + totalA);
    }else if ($(this).val() =='20.00'){

        var a = $("#sff").val();
        var b = $("#osf").val();
       var totalA = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);

        totalA = parseFloat(totalA) + 20.00;
        $('#total').val('$' + totalA);
    }else if ($(this).val() =='30.00'){

        var a = $("#sff").val();
        var b = $("#osf").val();
        var totalA = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);

        totalA = parseFloat(totalA) + 30.00;
        $('#total').val('$' + totalA);
    }
    });
  }
```